# What is the velocity of earth due to the rotational motion of the earth moon system about the center of mass?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, gravity

If someone can please help me with this question as I can not get my head around it.

Comment: Hint: $v= \omega r$. You know $\omega$, now find the barycenter of the system to get $r$,

Answer (score 1):

You can easily calculate the center of mass of both bodies by using the mass of the earth, moon and the distance between them. Now calculate the force exerted by the moon on earth using the gravitational force formula. Equate to centripetal force and isolate $v$.